# Disabling pull down control/notification center on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I am overriding this on my view controller to disable pulling down notification screen in case user is swiping down near the top.

```
  override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
       return [.top]
  }
```

This works fine when I do pull near the center from the top, but the moment I start pulling down from the top left or right corners, it pulls down the control or notification menu. How do I disable it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it can't be disabled. The best you can do is change the behaviour for full screen apps:

Swiping down over the area previously occupied by the status bar will only show a little tab. Only swiping the tab will then show the notification center. This has been enough to prevent accidental activation for me so far.

```
statusBarHidden = YES
```